# Refactor my Code implementing Repositories in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I'm refactoring all my DB Access related to my User Model in my Laravel app implementing Repositories.

So, now, all my DB Access ( I use Eloquent ) go through my UserRepository.

But I still have some eloquent operations in my model User:

```
class User extends Model{
....
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($user) {
        $softDeletedUser = User::onlyTrashed()->where('email', '=', $user->email)->first();
        if ($softDeletedUser != null) {
            $softDeletedUser->restore();
            return false;
        } else {
            $user->token = str_random(30);
            if ($user->country_id == 0) {
                $user->addGeoData();
            }


        }
        return true;
    });
```

I don't know what to do with that because:

1. It's about my User Model, not my Controller
2. It is a static method, so I don't know how to pass $this with (use)
3. I guess there is something wrong with that....

So... What should I do in this situation?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: well, create an abstraction layer for User Model using Repository and dependency.... It's the first time I implement the technique. All my call in Controllers are OK, but this call, I don't know what to do with it.... Should I let it as it is?

Comment: you might find this article helpful: https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/ (and if you want to go even further read this one) http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services

Comment: Yep, tx, I already saw it. It is a nice post!

Comment: Considering the way you're using this, you may also look into a Service oriented pattern. Just remember there's no _right_ way to organize code, just what makes the most sense for your application and most importantly for you and your team.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you really need to move that query into a repository but it's up to you to decide. If you really need to reuse that code, add the query into a repository class and use it. Using the same query on 2 places isn't really a big deal but it might become a problem if you have more than 2 places.